# Python: Usage of ^ operator within a print expression: {^:61}.format

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, string-formatting

I am watching a video about the concept of Cross Validation. Here is a code snippet from that video:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
kf = KFold(25, n_folds=5, shuffle=False)

print '{}{:^61}{}'.format('Iteration', 'Training set observations', 'Testing set observations')
for iteration,data in enumerate(kf, start=1):
    print '{:^9}{}{:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], data[1])
```

My question, however, is about the formatting used within print: What does the `{:^61}` do, for example? I have never seen the `^` within the braces used for print formatting. It is usually sth like `{0:3.2f}`. I know that `^` can be used as XOR, but, what is it doing here?

Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It centers the text within the field, where the field is 61 characters wide.

This is documented in the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

> `'^'`
>   Forces the field to be centered within the available space.

Note that there are also options for left and right alignment (using `'<'` and `'>'`, respectively), as well as a number-specific `=` option to put the padding between the value and the positive or negative sign.

Different object types have different formatting specifications; Python essentially takes the part after `:` from `{...:...}` and delegates the formatting to the object being formatted, via the [`__format__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__). So while numbers support specifications like `3.2f`, there many more possible formatting specifiers. For example, `datetime.date()`, `datetime.date()` and `datetime.time()` objects take [`strftime()` formatting specification strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), and you can implement your own in custom Python classes.

Comment: ah, okay! So, does the 61 give the size of the field then?

Comment: @Luk: yes, 61 is the field width. Without a field width, the default is the length of the formatted value, at which point it's futile to centre that value.